# How to enable USB Debugging in IOS 7

Tags: ios, xamarin, usb-debugging

I cant understand, how to debug? In android it in "Settings - Developer options - USB debugging". but in iphone with ios 7 I cant find it. Maybe the developer options menu is hidden, but how to show it?

I'm using Xamarin.IOS in Windows 8.

Answer (score 7):

iOS does not allow any kind of USB debugging with an ordinary device. If you have paid for an Apple Developer account, then after provisioning your device, developer options will become available. However, unless you have done that, you will not be able to debug.

It's a sad fact.

Comment: To add to this, notably, you can't distribute to an iOS device without a Mac either.

Comment: You can distribute to an iOS device without a mac.  Generate your package with an AdHoc or development provision and download your file to your phone.

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin announced the new "iOS USB Remoting" feature that allows you to deploy and debug to an iOS device that is attached to your Windows pc. However, you still need a mac for building:
http://sdtimes.com/xamarin-announces-new-ways-developers-build-ios-apps-visual-studio/#ixzz47U7prhgb

The forum says that this feature is planned for cycle 8 which is in alpha at the moment:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/65834/ios-usb-remoting

Btw: macincloud.com is a great alternative to having a physical mac.